# The Comey-McCabe Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

**Edited short question (this paragraph was not written by the OP)**

There are two particular people of interest in a population of $154000000$. We randomly select a batch of 5000 different people from the population (sampling without replacement and equally likely over all choices). What is the probability that both of the 2 people of interest are in the batch?

---

**Background (the original post)**
Recently, a question of probabilities has entered the collective political dialog. See

https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/news/comey-and-mccabe-audits-how-likely-that-they-were-a-coincidence/ar-AAZk4JO?ocid=mailsignout&li=BBnb7Kz

The discussion seems to suggest that the probability cannot be calculated and yet that evaluation of a potentially hypergeometric distribution could be a potential solution to this problem.

Despite some effort, enumeration problems are for me always difficult to grasp given the constant potential for considerable uncertainty as to precisely what should be counted.  Nonetheless, in this case it would seem that the principle of inclusion/exclusion should apply.

Nonetheless, from my reading the foundations of probability theory rest on the assumption of the sigma-additivity of probabilities of independent events (ie the probability of the union of two disjoint sets equals the probability of their sum).  Assuming this is correct and assuming that the Comey and McCabe audits are truly random, independent events then one must infer that they are disjoint events for purposes of enumeration of the size of the sample space of their intersection (both audits occurring together by chance).

Follow this reasoning, one may infer that the chance (given the values present in the article) that the probability of either event occurring is 1/Binomial[154000000, 5000] (ie 154 million choose 5000) and 1/Binomial[154000000,4000]) respectively (ignoring error in assuming the estimating the actual numbers of returns and audits in each year), which represent the number of ways such an outcome could occur.  With their intersection being derived by multiplying their probabilities. However, this seems to be a much, much smaller number (by my calculation 1.8 x 10^-44688) than the 1 in 950,000,000 stated in the article.  Indeed, much smaller than Edington's number.

Further, the article seems to imply that use of a hypergeometric distribution should be assumed, even though that distribution assumes no replacement, which would not seem to be the case since all parties are potentially subject to audit every year.

Can someone explain from first principles precisely how this probability should be calculated under the assumption that both events are truly random variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't much like advocacy here. Voted to close

Comment: This is not a maths question. It belongs on crossvalidated

Comment: I am simply asking how one should set up the enumeration problem.  Clearly a math problem.  No advocacy intended.  How one should correctly pose and answer the question in the context of statistical inference.  I calculate one sample space as having Binomial[154000000,4000] possible outcomes and another having Binomial[154000000,5000] possible outcomes.  If these sample spaces are independent then shouldn't the probability of the first be 1/Binomial[15000000,4000] and the second be 1/Binomial[154000000,5000] so that their intersection is their product since the events are disjoint?

Answer (score 2):

I have taken the liberty to edit your post with a clear and answerable math question.

In your original post, you seem to conflate "independent" and "disjoint" which are two different things.

Also your number $1/{154000000 \choose 5000}$ is not correct. That would be the (infinitesimally small) probability that a particular group of 5000 people you have designated in advance are exactly the group of 5000 that is selected. If you want the probability that **1 particular person** is in a group of 5000 selected from 154000000, the exact answer is:
$$ \frac{5000}{154000000}$$
If you want the probability that  **2 particular people** are both in a group of 5000 selected from 154000000, the hypergeometric distribution gives the exact answer:
$$\boxed{\frac{{2 \choose 2}{154000000-2\choose 4998}}{{154000000 \choose 5000}}=\left(\frac{5000}{154000000}\right)\left(\frac{4999}{153999999}\right)\approx \frac{1}{948829759}}$$
which is in good agreement with the 1 in 950 million quoted in the article.

---

Addressing the larger question: Fix the population size $n=154000000$ and designate $k=400$ people of interest. We look over three years and there are $5000+4000+8000=17000$ audits over those years. Assuming none of those audits include the same person twice, the probability that at least 2 of the $k$ people of interest show up as audited at some point in the three year span is
$$ 1 - \frac{{k \choose 0}{n-k \choose 17000}}{{n \choose 17000}} - \frac{{k \choose 1}{n-k \choose 16999}}{n \choose 17000} \approx \frac{1}{1059}$$
which is about 1 in a thousand.

However, this leaves out the issue that the IRS does not select people in an equally likely fashion, which  the article brings up as an important factor. This means the audits favor selection of high-income people. If most or all of the $k=400$ high-interest people are in the high-income group, then the small number 1/1059 would increase to a larger number.

---

Suppose the true number is $\beta \geq 1/1059$. This is the probability that 2 or more people of interest are audited given there is no audit manipulation.  Let $S$ be the (surprising) event that 2 or more people of interest are audited, and $M$ be the event of audit manipulation.  Then assuming $P[S|M^c]=\beta$ and $P[S|M]=1$ we get by Baye's rule the probability that no manipulation took place, given that the surprising event happened:
\begin{align}
P[M^c|S] &= \frac{P[S|M^c]P[M^c]}{P[S|M^c]P[M^c]+P[S|M]P[M]} \\
&= \frac{\beta(1-P[M])}{\beta(1-P[M]) + P[M]}
\end{align}
and $P[M|S]=1-P[M^c|S]$.
This depends on $P[M]$, the a-priori probability that manipulation took place.  We do not know the value of $P[M]$, but for a given $\beta$ you can plot $P[M^c|S]$ versus $P[M] \in [0, 1]$ to get a curve that may be of interest.

Comment: So an important question is how many enemies did President Trump have in the years in question

Comment: @Henry : I used the number $k=400$ as suggested as the conservative upper bound in the article (the article mentioned a chart but I did not find a chart). It states: "Here is a chart of the probability our equation yields at different choices for the number of red marbles, ranging from two (Mr. Comey and Mr. McCabe and no one else) to 400."

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer.  This was the explanation I was looking for.  Since reading the initial article, the exact numbers for both returns and numbers of audits in the years in question seem to now be reported as slightly differently, but the initial figures are in the same ballpark.

Comment: Was anyone else able to see the "chart" the article referred to? Perhaps it was not rendered in the link that seems to reprint the article.